# Histogram type highcharts access to series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a histogram type highcharts, and I need inside the chart event update function get access to `series[0].data` for changing points color.  I can see `series[0].data` array with all my points in google dev tools, but actually get an empty array in JS code. After the updated color of points does not change. Example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/azovez/qprty2z7/59)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such event as `chart.events.update`. Use the render instead - API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/csdnh6e3/

```
chart: {    
    events: {
      render: function() {
        console.log('data :', this.series[0].data);
        this.series[0].data.forEach(data => data.update({ 
            color: '#0f5'
        }, false)); // after the update() color of points does not change
      }
    }
  },
```